# How to change "Open With" option for folder in Mavericks

Tags: macos, finder

My Desktop folder is set to launch terminal. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to reset that.

I have deleted /Users/username/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist and that did not fix it. I installed OnyX, and ran Rebuild Launch Services. I tried changing the open with option to Finder, but I couldn't locate it.

I'm about to wipe and start over. Any thoughts?

Just to be clear, this is on both the the Favorites sidebar, and the actual folder itself.

Comment: There is no open with for folders in os x finder. you must hvae another app doing that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm by no means certain, but it sounds like you have managed to attach an Automator action to it somehow. A folder shouldn't have any kind of File Association/Open With attached to it.

Does the same happen if you manually drill down to the same folder HD/Users/[name]/Desktop ?

Comment: In any finder window, yes. If I open up the disk itself, and locate the Desktop folder, terminal opens. If I do it in console, I can see the contents of /Desktop and it does not open a new terminal window.

Answer (score 1):

```
xattr -c ~/Desktop
```

this solved it for me.